# Error on Truffle console - "missing ) after argument list"

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

while declaring a variable in truffle console error popped up. Code:-

```
var ss
undefined
truffle(development)> ScoreStore.deployed().then(function(deployd){ss=deployed;});
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 1):

"deployed" in your function body should be "deployd" with no "e"?